# measure text height on an html5 canvas element

Tags: html, text, html5-canvas, measurement

I know I can use context.measureText to get the width of some text if it would now be rendered on the canvas.
Is there a way to do the same but get the text's height?

just a thought to myself - maybe I can rotate the text 90Deg and then test for the width ?...

Comment: Look here for a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas

Comment: I posted a solution with a simple function here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36729322/1828637

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you find the height of text on an HTML canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas)

Answer (score 6):

This SO answer is probably over-engineered for your needs
[How can you find the height of text on an HTML canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas)

I prefer something a little more simple:

```js
var text = "Hello World";
var font = "Serif";
var size = "16";
var bold = false;

var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = text;
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.style.top  = '-9999px';
    div.style.left = '-9999px';
    div.style.fontFamily = font;
    div.style.fontWeight = bold ? 'bold' : 'normal';
    div.style.fontSize = size + 'pt'; // or 'px'
document.body.appendChild(div);
var size = [ div.offsetWidth, div.offsetHeight ];
document.body.removeChild(div);

// Output
console.log( size );
var pre = document.getElementById( "output" );
if( pre )
    pre.innerHTML = size;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Reference:
http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/measuring-text-height-with-html5-canvas.html

Comment: Where is the canvas?

Comment: You don't _need_ a canvas for metrics.

Comment: You do need a canvas when the question is about canvas.

Comment: 16px font in a `<div>` is the same size as 16px font in a `<canvas>` assuming the canvas hasn't been scaled so, no, the canvas isn't needed in this answer. @JorgeFuentesGonzález

Comment: @JesseStrickland First: canvas `measureText` is sub-pixel accurate, not like `offsetWidth`, so is not the exact same result. Second: Chrome is not 100% browsers. Some time ago Microsoft Edge had some problems with this. I guess that now being Chromium has the exact same result as Chrome, but still is not the same result because of sub-pixel precission (and you don't know how all browsers implement this, so if you are going to work with canvas, measure text with canvas. That's an easy "good practice" rule to avoid implementation problems).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and what I found is this.
Get the font size from you string.
I do not know why, but it only works when you set the proprety in PT, not PX.

```
ctx.font="20px Georgia"; // This will not work.
ctx.font="20pt Georgia"; // This is what we need.
```

Then take the value from it.

```
var txtHeight = parseInt(ctx.font);
```

Now you have the height for your text.
Like I said, in my side I had to set the size in PT as PX

Comment: if you set the font weight or (another style parameter) it will return for example `bold 40px verdana` so the `parseInt` will fail...

Comment: fontheight = parseInt(ctx.font.match(/\d+/), 10);

Answer (score 1):

You can set the font size of your canvas in pixels which you SHOULD then be able to use as the height of your text box. However, when I came to do this I found I needed to add approximately 50% to the pixel height to get an accurate value:

```
var textHeight = fontSize * 1.5;
```

If that's not good enough for you, there are a couple of pretty full-blown solutions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas), one of which uses the `getImageData` method to count the number of vertical pixels.

Comment: This is dependent on font type and it assumes there are no extremely interesting characters.