# What's this mystery gap between the div and text?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of trouble with a large gap between the top and bottom of a DIV when adding text. It looks like it's the calculated height of the text but why is it out so much? Ideally I need it to be as flush as possible to the border.

I've created a simple fiddle to demonstrate this http://jsfiddle.net/XFqq5/3/

**CSS**

```
#text {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 70px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 line-height: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="text">test</div>
```

Comment: Try lowering the line-height. What you're seeing is normal, it's the space that would be filled if you had capital letters.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161385/how-to-get-the-real-height-of-a-text

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a combination of:

- You aren't using the tallest or lowest glyphs in the font (type a capital letter and one with a descender such as `g` or `y`) *and*
- There's no rule which says the glyphs have to stretch the entire height of the font

Comment: The problem is it could be one of several fonts chosen by a user and not necessarily include letters of the tallest or lowest glyphs but I need to it the border to be as accurate as possible. How would I force a rule using JS or other means to stretch it only to the letters I have in there?

Comment: Maybe render it in a `<canvas>` and then measure pixel colours before drawing the border.

Comment: I got it to work in the end using canvas and measuring the pixel colours as you suggested which ended up being fairly accurate, I will accept your answer cheers for your help. Even when I was using the tallest glyphs it was still wrong infact some of the descenders they were even peeping out the border.