# 1 div into 2 separate div's with equal height using with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible 1 div into 2 separate div's with equal height **using with jQuery**? Its dynamic content, so we don't know the exact height of the content.

1. First find the outer div height and divide by 2 that outer div height(Using jQuery)
2. Second insert two child div's along with outer div (Using jQuery)

I already tried this below code:(Its word count method, but now I need content height method)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mydiv").each(function(div) {
   var div_height = $(this).text().split(' ');       
   var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < div_height.length; i += 105) {     
    out.push('<div class="wrapper">' + div_height.slice(i, i+105).join(' ') + '</div>' + '<br>');
    } 

   $(this).html(out.join(' '));
  });
});
</script>
```

Example: If outer div height is 100px, I will divide two inner divs with 50px(inner1) and 50px(inner2) height.

```
<div id="outer">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.    
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>    
  <div id="inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your explanation is not clear!!, please try with another figure of speech.

Comment: Assign height value to the css max-height property for those divs.

Comment: Don't use inline styles, it's ugly and unmaintainable.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs on how to resolve this???

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to ask -- how does one split text in a element to fit a certain height. One can use this for the purpose to taking text in a `<div/>` and splitting it into two `<div/>`s.

The simple answer is - split the text in the middle, e.g.

```
var outer = $('outer');
var words = outer.text().split(' ');
outer.empty();
var inner1 = $('<div/>').addClass('inner').appendTo(outer);
var inner2 = $('<div/>').addClass('inner').appendTo(outer);
var middle = parseInt(words.length/2);
inner1.text(words.slice(0, middle).join(' '));
inner2.text(words.slice(middle));
```

Note that this assumes that `outer` only contains uniform text. If it contains styled elements or images, this gets more complicated. Even in the case of uniform text, it might produce a results that is off by a line here or there. Also, splitting by spaces might cut sentences in the middle, which may or may not suit your needs.

You could make this just finer by:

1. splitting your text in a finer manner. You can even go to the level of adding hyphens between syllables of words - again, depending on your need.
2. searching for the best place to split. I think a binary search for the number of words (or sentences, or whatever you decide to break your text into) is the quickest, simplest way to do this. I wrote a small example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VYgRpQ). Also, see the question: [How to get the real height of a text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161385/how-to-get-the-real-height-of-a-text).

You'll need to define your problem a bit better, if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Hi Yuval your code is very useful for me. Thank you so much, but I need still more help from you. 1. Images and table not show in my content (ex: <div id="outer">
<img style="float:left; margin-right:10px;" src="cow.jpg">Location 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
   <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td>
   <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
</div>)

Comment: Yuval --- My updated code is available here : http://jsfiddle.net/gsk/r9udxg1m/2/ - Kindly verify and give me the best solution.

Comment: Hi Yuval - I am waiting for your reply. Kindly help me...

Comment: As I said, this solution suits a problem of having text-only in a `<div/>`. If your `<div/>` contains something other than text, it's not that simple to know how to split it. For instance, what if the image is big? Should this algorithm split the image? You have to figure out **what** you want to do, before you set out to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Gsk, your question is very vague, but I think you are looking for columns. Check CSS3 for columns http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

I am not 100% sure of the tables but it's worth looking into.

Comment: This is not suitable for me...

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>    
    <div id="inner2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer  {
    height: auto;
    padding: 0px:
}
#inner1  {
    margin: 0px;
}
#inner2  {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Its dynamic content, we don't know the height. they add the content in DB level. (I told that example only 50px)

Comment: Answer updated without fixed height

Answer (score 0):

use a class instead of ID on the inner div

```
    <style type = "text/css" >
    #outer{
    height:100%;
    min-height:set whatever you want.;
    }

    .inner{
     height: 50px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id = "outer">
    <div class = "inner"></div>
    <div class = "inner"></div>
    </div>
```

since the inner divs have the same format just use class instead of id..

Comment: Or you can use bootstrap..  http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: I need single div content split into two div's with jQuery (dynamically). I don't want static solution.

Comment: you need to clarify your questions.. it's too vague... you only need 1 inner div and loop it? is that it? loop if there is 3 result there should be 3 div is that it?

Comment: My updated code is available here : jsfiddle.net/gsk/r9udxg1m/2 - Kindly verify and give me the best solution.