# JavaScript Canvas – how to get area used by font

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How would I get the area occupied by a filled `ctx.font`? For example:

[image]

All my research points to baseline and `ctx.measureText(word);` which gives me the width (perfectly, I should add) but the height is something I'm really struggling with, as descenders seem to always be included in the calculation.

Can I bitmap the font and then calculate the scale that way?

Here is a (failing) canvas size function I was using:

```
function textSize(word, size){
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = word;
  div.style.position = 'absolute';
  div.style.fontFamily = 'serif';
  div.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  div.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  var size = {
    'width': div.offsetWidth,
    'height': div.offsetHeight
  };
  return size; // size.height would be much larger than required with fonts with no descenders
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can find answer by [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161385/how-to-get-the-real-height-of-a-text)?

Comment: What about those answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas

Comment: or this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17631567/3702797

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
context.fillText("Hello World!", 10, 100);
context.strokeText("Hello World!", 10, 100);
var textMetrics = context.measureText("Hello World!");
var width = textMetrics.width;

context.font = "20pt Arial";
context.fillText("Width of previous text: " + width + "pixels", 10, 150);
```