# EASELJS - underline text

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I haven't seen any native support for this in the framework, so i did some code, by measuring the font Height and drawing a line underneath. I need to find out how much Descent the font has, as getMeasureHeight only measures until the font baseline.

I have the following code, so far:

```
var textLayer = new createjs.Text();
var fontSizeInPx = Math.round((self.fontSize() / 72) * 300, 0) + "px";

textLayer.textBaseline = 'bottom';
textLayer.text = text;
textLayer.font = getFontStyle(self.isBold(), self.isItalic(), fontSizeInPx, 'Arial');;
var textMeasures = textLayer.getBounds();

var underlineShape = new createjs.Shape();

var startYCoords = self.positionY() + textMeasures.height;

underlineShape.graphics.beginStroke(self.color()).setStrokeStyle(2)
    .moveTo(self.positionX(), startYCoords)
    .lineTo(textMeasures.width + self.positionX(), startYCoords);
```

And this is the result:

[image]

How can i get this metric?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution here, for getting the font metrics: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9847841/3202740

Having the font descent, the only thing that has to be done is getting the font Height and adding the font descent:

```
var lineBreaks = self.canvasLayer.text.split("\n");

$.each(lineBreaks, function (idx, text) {
    if (text != '') {
        var textLayer = new createjs.Text();
        var fontSizeInPx = Math.round((self.fontSize() / 72) * 300, 0) + "px";

        textLayer.textBaseline = 'bottom';
        textLayer.text = text;
        textLayer.font = getFontStyle(self.isBold(), self.isItalic(), fontSizeInPx, 'Arial');;
        var textMeasures = textLayer.getBounds();
        var textMetrics = getTextHeight('Arial');

        var underlineShape = new createjs.Shape();

        var startYCoords = self.positionY() + (textMeasures.height * (idx+1));

        underlineShape.graphics.beginStroke(self.color()).setStrokeStyle(2)
            .moveTo(self.positionX(), startYCoords + textMetrics.descent)
            .lineTo(textMeasures.width + self.positionX(), startYCoords + textMetrics.descent);

        underlineShapes.push(underlineShape);

        self.canvasLayer.stage.addChild(underlineShape);
    }
});
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to take advantage of the `textBaseline` property. Setting it to `alphabetic` instead of `top` (the default) will draw your text with the font baseline at `y=0`. You can then grab the width with `getMeasuredWidth()`, and draw the line at the x & y of the Text object (possibly offsetting the y by a pixel or two to put it where you want).

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gskinner/y919oszd/

It's also worth noting that other baseline values, like "ideographic" are very unreliable, and behave differently on different browsers. The most reliable is "alphabetic", followed by "top", which is rendered incorrectly by FireFox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, i cannot simply add some extra pixels to Y coordinates of the underilne, every font has it's own descending measures, and, depending on the size of the Font, i would have to calculate how much extra i would have to add. Also, i have to use TOP as textbaseline because the coordinates are imported from a .psd file, which draws the text using top as font baseline.