# How can I set limit of lines in TextBox in .Net using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to set the maximum number of lines in Textbox  also I tried multiple places for this answer but I failed.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814398/how-can-i-check-if-a-scrollbar-is-visible/29188509#29188509) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134586/how-can-you-find-the-height-of-text-on-an-html-canvas/66597679#66597679) and then I have found an issue that keyboard of mobile is not working on Keypress event while It's working on keyboard of the desktop.

Please help me to find the answer.

Thank You for concentration.

Comment: [Please search better](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+limit+lines+textbox+site:stackoverflow.com) -  [here with mobile](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+limit+lines+textbox+mobile+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Thank you sir but I have issue that Keyboard of mobile is not working except Enter Key. @mplungjan

Comment: I did not find answer . Can ANtone help to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Lines used: 0

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var lines = 10;
var linesUsed = $('#linesUsed');

$('#countMe').keydown(function(e) {

    newLines = $(this).val().split("\n").length;
    linesUsed.text(newLines);

    if(e.keyCode == 13 && newLines >= lines) {
        linesUsed.css('color', 'red');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        linesUsed.css('color', '');
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Sir I used this it's not working.